# submit handler working only on second attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, recaptcha, form-submit

I'm using the [1000hz bootstrap validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) with my form before [Invisible reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) kicks in. To do so, I had to use a jQuery submit handler.

The problem is that the handler works only after the submit button is clicked twice. On the first click, the form is submitted, bypassing the handler and by doing so the invisible reCaptcha does not get executed and, of course, I get an error.

This is the form:

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="true" id="contactform" method="post" action="result.php">
  <div class="form-group"><label for="InputName1">Envianos un E-mail</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameofuser" placeholder="Nombre, Apellido" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="InputEmail1">Email</label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Tu E-mail" required data-error="Porfavor, ingrese una dirección de Email valida.">
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="InputName1">Mensaje</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="6LfCKjQUAAAAAPSp2YVmv-Yv2sOIPW_gp6CLVBUj"
    data-callback="onCompleted"
    data-size="invisible">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" style="font-size: 24px;" class="btn btn-box openSans" >Enviar</button>
</form>
```

And this the JS:

```
$("#contactform").submit(function(e) {

  $('#contactform').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      // handle the invalid form...
      console.log("FORM INVALIDO");
    } else {
      // everything looks good!
      if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
        console.log('captcha not yet completed.');
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
        grecaptcha.execute();
      } else {
        console.log('form really submitted.');
      }
    }
  })
});

onCompleted = function() {
    console.log('captcha completed.');
    $("#contactform").submit();
}
```

If someone wants to look at the console, here is a page showing the issue:
https://ccromatica.com/contacto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining an event handler inside the submit callback.

The code `$('#contactform').validator().on('submit')` isn't registered until you first submit the form. The second time you submit the form, the event handler kicks into action and does what it's meant to do.

The simplest solution is to move all event handlers, like the one mentioned above, outside of any submit functions.

Make sure that whenever you're defining an event handler, it's run first, rather than only being defined based on some other condition.

Comment: I have removed the submit function and now the event handler works great, in first click, at least that is what the console shows. but the form sends to result.php only on second click.

Comment: What does the console show on first and second click? Assuming it passes validation, there's nothing there that should block the form submission. I also notice you have `event.preventDefault();`, when `event` isn't defined. Should be `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I have fixed e.preventDefault();
On first click: 
captcha not yet completed.
captcha completed.
form really submitted.

On second click just:
form really submitted.

So the logic is working as it should on both clicks.